# Get checkboxes (with the same name) as array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML form that contains a set of checkboxes:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="apple" /> Apple</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="banana" /> Banana</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="strawberry" /> Strawberry</p>
```

When I click a button I want to have all the selected checkboxes with the same name in one array.

So, if the user selects Apple and Banana I expect something like this:

```
{ 'fruits' : [ 'Apple', 'Banana' ] }
```

I tried to use jQuery's serializeArray() method but the result is not as I expected...

```
[ { name="fruits",  value="apple"}, { name="fruits",  value="banana"} ]
```

I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzeVU/2/) with my example code.

I know I could iterate over this array and create the object I want. But my question is:
**Is there a *clean & simple* way (using jQuery or some plugin) to do this?**

**Edit: ** I'm looking for some kind of generic solution to this problem. I'd like to tell a method the form element and have that method automatically find all data. Just like the jQuery.serializeArray() does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` method.

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.fruits = $('input[name=fruits]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(obj);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62f3X/1/

You can use also create the properties using `name` properties:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
    var obj = {};
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) 
            obj[this.name] = [this.value];
        else 
            obj[this.name].push(this.value);
    });
    // console.log(obj);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62f3X/2/

Comment: I like the look of this! But I still have to manually set `obj.fruits`. Is it possible just to pass the form element and have a method determine the name and values by itself?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to achieve this but you could do:

```
var fruits = [];

$('#selectAll').click(function() {
   $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
   $("input[name=fruits]:checked").each(function() {
     var fruit = $(this).val();
     fruits.push(fruit);
  });

  console.log(fruits);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NzeVU/3/

Comment: I prefer this solution to the accepted one.  Could even trim a line and just push $(this).val() or $(this).value.